# Can this infinite sum be approximated to a special function of any kind?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, special-functions

I have the following infinite sum

$$ H(z) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{C}{C+i}\right)^n \ln\left(\frac{C}{C+i}\right) \frac{z^i}{i!}$$

Without the logarithm term, I am able to write it as a generalized hypergeometric function, but with the logarithm, I have no idea. Can it be written in terms of special functions?

Here $C > 0, n > 1$, $z \quad \epsilon \quad \mathbb{C} $

Without the logarithm:

$$ G(z) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{C}{C+i}\right)^n \frac{z^i}{i!} = _n F_n(C, C, ..., C; C+1, C+1, ..., C+1; z) $$

Comment: Where does the problem comes from ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The physical problem from which this comes is difficult to explain, but I will try. The sum without the logarithm comes from a correlation function of a signal in time, which contains the scattering of an ensemble of particles, the diameters of which are gamma-distributed with size parameter $n-6$, and mean diameter $1/(C \times 0.6) \text{cm}$.  The sum I wrote with the logarithm is an attempt to find the derivative of the expression without the logarithm with respect to $n$.